# Javascript loop not working properly (FRAME UPDATE LOOP)

Tags: javascript

When I try to run the following code, on my console log, I get "Done!!", instead of getting

> currentFrame=0
>
> sourceX=0

It's suppose to have a counter, and with and interval of every 300 millisecond, it's
suppose to update the "currentFrame" and "sourceX" variable. The condition is true nevertheless It doesn't output anything but "Done!!".

- Note
  : yes, all elements on the page are loaded properly

The following is my code:.

```
            var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
            var drawingSurface = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var tileSheet = new Image();
            tileSheet.src="frames.png";

            var msperFrame = 300;

            var interval;
            SIZE=128;

            tileSheet.addEventListener("load",loadHandler,false);

            var monster={
                frames:6,
                SIZE:128,
                currentFrame:0,
                sourceX:0,
                sourceY:0,
                updateAnimation: function(){
                    var self=this;
                    if(self.currentFrame <= self.frames){
                        self.sourceX = self.currentFrame*this.SIZE;
                        console.log("Current Frame: "+self.currentFrame+"\nSourceX: "+self.sourceX);
                        self.currentFrame++;
                        render();
                    }else{
                        console.log("Done!!");
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }
            };

            function loadHandler(){
                interval = window.setInterval(monster.updateAnimation,msperFrame);
            }

            function render(){
                drawingSurface.drawImage(tileSheet,
                monster.sourceX,monster.sourceY,monster.SIZE,monster.SIZE,
                0,0,monster.SIZE,monster.SIZE);
            }
```

Comment: @TalhaTanveer you may get `Done` infinitely but before that do you have your code executed as expected (It seems like some sort of animation)?

Comment: @Leron yeah, the question's already answered though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that's a funny bug :-)

Your problem is `this`: When run by `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, it defaults to `window`, not `monster`. Try this:

```
interval = window.setInterval(function(){monster.updateAnimation();},msperFrame);
```

By wrapping it inside an anonymous function, you should be fine. You're getting "Done!!" because both properties in `if (window.currentFrame <= window.frames)` are undefined.

Side notes:

You're using `this.SIZE` instead of `self.SIZE`.

300 ms per render loop might produce a chunky animation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it will produce a chunky loop, I am just testing, this isn't my actual game though.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(monster.updateAnimation,msperFrame);
```

will in effect get translated into

```
window.setInterval(function(){
                var self=this; //here 'this' is window
                if(self.currentFrame <= self.frames){
                    self.sourceX = self.currentFrame*this.SIZE;
                    console.log("Current Frame: "+self.currentFrame+"\nSourceX: "+self.sourceX);
                    self.currentFrame++;
                    render();
                }else{
                    console.log("Done!!");
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                }
            },msperFrame);
```

This function will be run from `global` scope, or from `window` scope. So `this` will be `window` object.

When you do

```
window.setInterval(function(){monster.updateAnimation();},msperFrame);
```

as @erik suggested http://jsfiddle.net/Vn3s7/

```
function(){monster.updateAnimation();}
```

will be run from `window` scope. As `monster` is available as `global` in `window` scope, 'moster.updateAnimation' is available and will be called with `this` pointer as `monster` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I shall vote up once I've got 15 reputation as I am new to stack overflow :P